# Access Denied running Remote PowerShell but only when ran from dev server, works fine localy

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server

I am trying to run a remote PowerShell command against our exchange server but am getting an `Access Is Denied` error when that command is ran from our development server. The code works fine when I run it on my local machine, I can even remote to the development server and run a PowerShell command and make the connection perfectly fine. I need help in figuring out why we are getting the `Access Is Denied` error when only running the code from the development server.

```
public static void CreateEmailBox(string samAccountName)
{
    var securedPassword = new SecureString();
    foreach (char character in ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceAccountPassword"]) { securedPassword.AppendChar(character); }
    var loginInfo = new PSCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceAccountUser"], securedPassword);

    var connection = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri("http://exch-svr.domain.local/powershell"), "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange", loginInfo);
    connection.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Kerberos;

    using (var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connection))
    {
        using (var powershell = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            powershell.AddCommand("enable-mailbox");
            powershell.AddParameter("Identity", samAccountName);
            powershell.AddParameter("Database", "Mailbox Database 4");
            runspace.Open();
            powershell.Runspace = runspace;
            powershell.Invoke();
            runspace.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is remote powershell enabled [see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/4.0/microsoft.powershell.core/enable-psremoting)?

Comment: I can run this code on my local machine with no problems so I believe it is enabled, it is only when I deploy the code to the development server does it fail to connect.

Comment: but if you use the code on your remote machine there is no "remove Powershell" or I miss understand your setup.

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?  `runspace.Open()`?  `powershell.Invoke()`?  Or is `powershell.Invoke()` *returning* that error from `Enable-Mailbox`?

Comment: @BaconBits Digging in the error log looks like it is at `runspace.Open()`

Comment: I get lots of potential results if I Google "access denied opening powershell runspace."  A cursory examination gives a lot of possibilities, however.  It could be a matter of elevation, a matter of improper impersonation, or an instance of a two-hop Kerberos problem.  My guess is one of the first two, but I've not done this type of thing before.

Answer (score 0):

The issue would be with the password, and how it is being stored as the Secure String.

Secure Strings are different between computers because the encryption key used to encrypt/decrypt the password is different on every computer.

You either need to use a shared key, or store a separate Secure String for each computer that you are going to run this from.

For more information, on how to pass Secure Strings between computers see my more detailed Answer on: [ConvertTo-SecureString gives different experience on different servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699500/convertto-securestring-gives-different-experience-on-different-servers/23700513#23700513)